# wpallimport, run function 'dont_create_terms' only for specidied taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms, wpallimport

So, prefix that my coding level is practically equal to zero...

I'm using Wordpress with Wp All Import plugin, and i have this code to prevent wpallimport to create new categories/taxonomies etc.

```
function dont_create_terms( $term_into, $tx_name ) {

// Check if term exists, checking both top-level and child
// taxonomy terms. 
$term = empty($term_into['parent']) ? term_exists( $term_into['name'], $tx_name, 0 ) : term_exists( $term_into['name'], $tx_name, $term_into['parent'] );

// Don't allow WP All Import to create the term if it doesn't
// already exist.
if ( empty($term) and !is_wp_error($term) ) { 
    return false;
}

// If the term already exists assign it.
return $term_into;

}

add_filter( 'pmxi_single_category', 'dont_create_terms', 10, 2 );
```

Now, as specified in the title, i have to run this code only for certain taxonomies...

I have tried multiple solutions, for last i tried to add this line

```
   if ($tx_name == 'taxonomyname') {
```

like here

```
    function dont_create_terms( $term_into, $tx_name ) {
        
    // Check if term exists, checking both top-level and child
    // taxonomy terms. 
    $term = empty($term_into['parent']) ? term_exists( $term_into['name'], $tx_name, 0 ) : term_exists( $term_into['name'], $tx_name, $term_into['parent'] );

if ($tx_name == 'taxonomyname') {

    
    // Don't allow WP All Import to create the term if it doesn't
    // already exist.
    if ( empty($term) and !is_wp_error($term) ) { 
        return false;
    }

        // If the term already exists assign it.
        return $term_into;
    
    }

add_filter( 'pmxi_single_category', 'dont_create_terms', 10, 2 );
```

but everytime nothing appens.

Any help is really appreciated, thanks to everyone in advance

***Edit:***

**Solution found**

```
function dont_create_terms( $term_into ) {
    

// Check if term exists, checking both top-level and child
// taxonomy terms. 
$term = empty($term_into['parent']) ? term_exists( $term_into['name'], $tx_name, 0 ) : term_exists( $term_into['name'], $tx_name, $term_into['parent'] );

    if ( $tx_name == 'taxonomy_name' ){

// Don't allow WP All Import to create the term if it doesn't
// already exist.
if ( empty($term) and !is_wp_error($term) ) { 
    return false;
}

    // If the term already exists assign it.
    return $term_into;


}

add_filter( 'pmxi_single_category', 'dont_create_terms', 10, 2 );
```

And than call the function:

```
[dont_create_terms({yourxmldata[1]})]
```

**Edit 2**

**It only works with single taxonomies, if the taxonomies contain multiple values it will not work**

So again, if you have any suggestions you are welcome

Comment: "Nothing happens"?.. You need to debug this. [Set up debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and print out the taxonomy name into the debug.log, then go from there.

Comment: Sorry for the probably stupid question, I have enabled debugging several times, but how can I print taxonomy in the debug.log?

Comment: `error_log("taxonomy name: " . $tx_name);` plus enable debugging of course: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this would be writing your our custom function as shown here: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/code-snippets/#reference-taxonomy-terms-by-custom-id

However, although it is not elegant at all, I have found a different solution that could work for some, which involves wp-all-import's [foreach()] function.

It is not flexible as it requires that you add the max amount of values possible in your file (e.g 6 values tops in this example):

> [foreach( {ParentNode/CategoryNode} )] {@id} > {Value[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YK66.png)} |
> {@id} > {Value[2]} | {@id} > {Value[3]} | {@id} > {Value[4]} |
> {@id} > {Value[5]} | {@id} > {Value[6]} | [endforeach]

Where {ParentNode/CategoryNode} + @id + Value represent this portion of the xml file:

```
    <ParentNode>
      <CategoryNode id="this-cat-id">
          <Value>Your value here</Value>
      </CategoryNode>
    </ParentNode>
```

Important: This will generate this error log while importing, every time it tries to import a value that does not exist, but the import will still work:
`WARNING: It is necessary to assign a name to this term.`

**Important:**

(1) In the import settings, you will need to go to 'Taxonomies, Categories, Tags', and select 'An element in my file contains the entire hierarchy...'.

(2) Then, check 'Separate hierarchy groups via symbol'.

(3) **Do not** check 'Only assign Your-cat-name-goes-here to the bottom level term in the hierarchy'

Here is how I set it up....
[Screenshot WPAllImport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YK66.png)

Hope this helps newcomers!